# GParted cannot expand root partition

Tags: gparted, resize, unallocated

[image]

How can I expand root "/" partition by that 4.48GB unallocated partition?

I have LiveCD with GParted, but I dont know how to shift that partition.

Comment: Are you using LVM?

Comment: maybe no, i just installed standard ubuntu

Comment: @karel no this is different situation

Comment: I would say you have too much Windows, too little Ubuntu...

Comment: @CelticWarrior I dont understand

Comment: @tomsk First of all, the machine is yours, you do as you wish. I wouldn't install any current (modern desktop) Linux distro in less than 16GB total, preferably 32GB.

Comment: It is for testing and learning, later I will wipe Windows :) And in Windows partition I have unmoveable files, so it is quite hard to increase size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Warning: Make sure you have a backup in case anything goes wrong.**

Quick step-by-step:

1. Boot to live media.  **Do not mount any hard drives or partitions.**
2. Run gparted.  **Choose swapoff for swap partition by right-clicking swap.**
3. Expand/Resize `Extended partition (sda2)` to take up 4GB of remaining unallocated space.
4. Move `swap partition (sda7)` to end of Extended partition.
5. Move `/home (sda6)` next to swap partition.
6. Expand/Resize `/ (sda5)` to take up rest of space between sda5 and sda6.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please 4th step, how can I move it?

Comment: @tomsk Highlight the partition, then click on Partition in the menu, then choose Resize/Move and drag that partition to the right so free space appears in front of it.

Comment: @tomsk If you see the little Key that means it is still mounted and cannot be moved or resized.  Right-click and choose Unmount, then you can Move or Resize the partitions.

Comment: And you need to swapoff before you can move swap.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Thank you!  Added to my answer.  =)

Comment: @tomsk Glad I could help!  =)